# My imploded string wont insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had an multidimensional array which contained titles, links and descriptions for a collaboration of news stories crawled from the BBC News site.

I then used a function to implode it into a string, then defined the called function into a variable and inserted it into a database. But there is nothing being inserted. I have used the `die(mysql_error())` and nothing is being returned and I am struggling to think what I am doing wrong.

If I echo the variable I am inserting, I receive input similiar to the following: title, description, (where keywords should be), link, title, description, keywords link, title description, keywords, link.

Do you have any idea? Am I having some sort of quotation problem here?

```
 function r_implode( $glue, $pieces ) 
{ 
foreach( $pieces as $r_pieces ) 
{ 
    if( is_array( $r_pieces ) ) 
    { 
        $retVal[] = r_implode( $glue, $r_pieces ); 
    } 
    else
    { 
        $retVal[] = "'".$r_pieces."'";  //Here add quotes
    } 
} 
return implode( $glue, $retVal ); 
} 

$data = r_implode( ' , ', $news_stories); //And Here remove quotes
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_story (title, description, keywords, link) VALUES (". $data .")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It is not sufficient to just "have" some code. It is essential to be able to *debug* it. At least by printing it's result out.

Comment: You need to escape and quote every single array item. Oh, and don't use the deprecated *mysql* extension but use PDO/mysqli instead...

Comment: Assign the INSERT statement to a variable, and print that variable.  Something like `$sql_stmt="INSERT INTO news_story (title, description, keywords, link) VALUES (". $data .");"`. Also post the DDL for the MySQL table "news_story".

Comment: nothing is returned. blank web page

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be Quotaion problem here

```
function r_implode( $glue, $pieces ) 
{ 
    foreach( $pieces as $r_pieces ) 
    { 
        if( is_array( $r_pieces ) ) 
        { 
            $retVal[] = r_implode( $glue, $r_pieces ); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            $retVal[] = "'".$r_pieces."'";  //Here add quotes
        } 
    } 
    return implode( $glue, $retVal ); 
} 

$data = r_implode( ' , ', $news_stories); //And Here remove quotes
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_story (title, description, keywords, link) VALUES (". $data .")") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: yep it'll insert if `$data` must have exactly four value only..! less than that or more than four value meand it won't just echo the data and see wats it printing..? and reply with that @MatthewSmith

Comment: i havent given you an example of what its printing in the question. title,description,keywords,link,title,description,keywords,link,title,description,keywords,link etc.